# Printing contents with PHP

Tags: php

I can't really find a topic on how to print a file with the printer. 
First off, I dont't mean print like echo, but a real printer.

I want to have the user click on a button, and than it starts printing the page.

The same as javascript:window.print() does, but than with PHP. Is there such option?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to print on a printer attached to the web server or on one attached to the browser's PC?

Comment: Short answer: No, it is not possible! Only if you run php on a linux box and want to write to that machine's printer socket, maybe you could print something, but that not a real scenario, you seem to want a user from web to print on its printer. You could get it to print to your server's printer, tops!

Comment: No. Because PHP runs on the server and not in the clients browser.

Comment: I don't think that you can print a webpage with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean printing on server-side or client side?

For client-side you can include a javascript snippet which calls the JS function you mentioned:

```
<?php
print '<input type="button" value="Print this document" onclick="window.print();" />\n';
?>
```

For server-side: it is definitely more complicated. You could either find a PHP interface, e.g. to CUPS (the standard UNIX printing system) or call a system program that prints the document. Svish posted a link to <del>a CUPS interface as far as I see</del> an interface to printing in MS Windows (useful only if the server is running under Windows, of course).

Edit: If you expect to find a solution which prints the page PHP outputs rendered by the client browser and but not printed on the client, but on the server -- this should be impossible. I guess you could implement sending the output of PHP the a system program that renders the page itself but it will never look 100% like on the client. Maybe it's acceptable to call a printing program on the server, pass all necessary information to it and it renders some document of its own, e.g. an RTF text file?

Answer (score 1):

PHP works server-side and therefore cannot print anything on the client-side. It can't do *anything* on the client-side actually, other than via generated HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. PHP *can* [talk to a printer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) though, but it would be a server-side printer as far as I know.

SO, if you want the user to click a button to print a page, on their printer, it would have to be something client-side. For example JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As PHP is a server-side scripting language, this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the user print a document from his printer using PHP.

If the design of the printed document is undesirable, you can either add a print stylesheet.

Or have a printer friendly page.
For example; passing a get variable called printer will have your php script echo another design of your page.

If you are talking about a server-side printer, you can.