# HTML For Loop based on user selected number

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am making a quick site that allows users to register for an event. It consists of two pages, each with a form.

The first form/page gets their information, along with the number of people they will bring (1-20).  This form passes it's data to the next page.

The second page is a for loop that prints out x number of forms, based on the users selection from a dropdown menu.

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the first part done, the second page would have something similar to this:

```
<form>
<?
    $guestCount = $_POST['guestCount'];
    for($i=1; $i <= $guestCount;$i++) {
        echo "Guest $i <input type='text' name='guest$i' /><br />";
    }
?>
</form>
```

You're basically reading the number of guests submitted on the first form and displaying that many  tags.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_GET['number_of_forms']) {
    print_the_form();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolled into a self submitting page, something such as this should do;

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit']){
   $username=$_POST['username'];
   $amount=$_POST['amount'];    
   echo ("$username has invited $amount people");
   print_form($amount); 
}else{
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <label for="username">Your Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" />
   <label for="amount">Amount</label>
   <select name="amount">
       <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
           $el.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        print $el;      
       ?>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Then its just a matter of creating the `print_form()` function and passing it the amount of times to print.

You should maybe have a look at this thread also with regards '[Printing contents with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338821/printing-contents-with-php)'